# Can't delete uploaded files

Tags: php, file-upload, delete-file, safe-mode

When I try to delete uploaded file on my website with unlink function I get

```
Message: unlink() [function.unlink]: SAFE MODE Restriction in effect. The script whose uid/gid is 10566/2524 is not allowed to access /var/www/vhosts/websitename owned by uid/gid 0/0
```

I read that is a safe mode issue. OK but how to delete uploaded files ?

Comment: You should read : [PHP SAVE MODE](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php)

Comment: You need to have safe mode disabled. It is very restrictive and if any shared host has it on, it's time to move!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you should move (or delete) the uploaded file.

From the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

> The file will be deleted from the temporary directory at the end of
>   the request if it has not been moved away or renamed.

If cannot remove them, leave them. When your script finishes they will get deleted by the system.

Comment: What is the problem then? Why would you move the file and then want to delete it?

Answer (score -1):

In your PHP script that deletes the file, try to add, towards the top, the following instruction:

```
ini_set('safe_mode', 'off');
```

*EDIT*

If you don't have access to your web server's configuration, you could try to turn off safe_mode through an .htaccess file.

```
php_admin_flag safe_mode Off
```

Comment: It can only be disable form `php.ini`

Comment: According to http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?t=50477, you can disable it from htaccess, if the web server allows overrides.

Comment: Care to explain why safe_mode needs to be turned off?